# How to divide document in to columns html php and css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a web page with an image and title with a description and I want to put another column next to the image and title and text with the same structure.

I have this

```
        echo '<div class="gamedes">';
        echo '<img  class="miniaturas" src="recursos/miniaturas/coster.png" </img>';
        echo '<a class="gamede" href="game.php?name='.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a><br>';
        echo '<div class="description"><script>document.write("'.$row['description'].'".substring(0,120) + "<br>");</script></div><br><br><br><br>';
        echo '</div>';
```

And this css

```
.miniaturas {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.description {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 10%;
}

.gamede{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I want yo put the same structure image, title and description next to the first

I try to put a width to the description but it doesn't work.

Its like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjacu/t9r9S/4/

And I want to out the second image next to the first like in two columns

Comment: did you try setting up a table to fill the whole document, creating 1 row and as many columns as you need?

Comment: yes but I prefer no tables...

Comment: also possible with `<ul>` if you set `list-type:none` and `display:inline` to its `<li>` elements, it will be horizontal

Comment: could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net with your final html so we could see what you currently have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjacu/t9r9S/4/

Comment: I have this code and I want to put the second image, title and description in a column next to the first

Comment: i see, could you make a picture in mspaint how you want this whole thing to look like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want something like this:

```
img   |  img
title |  title
des   |  des

echo '<div class="gamedes">';
echo '<img  class="miniaturas" src="recursos/miniaturas/coster.png" />';
echo '<a class="gamede" href="game.php?name='.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
echo '<div class="description"> <script>           document.write("'.$row['description'].'".substring(0,120)"); </script><br /></div><p>';
echo '</div>';


css:

.gamedes{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}

.description{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

This should work.Give width to the div containing the structure so everything you put inside that div will fall in place.

Comment: Oh yes I want something like this!

Comment: But the title next to the img and the des down the title

Comment: do float:left to image class so anchor tag would float towards the right of image. And as you want the 'description' below then let its width be 100% so 'description' cannot be floated left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the question stems from two things - your current layout isn't quite working correctly and you are interested in adding another column to the existing layout. I adjusted your original code and removed the php (it isn't relevant for a layout question), then applied a `table-row` and `table-cell` based layout via css (*not* using an actual table tag). One other thing I did was I used div tags for layout rather than trying to force layout on specific tags such as the "a" tag. Doing this you end up with the following html:

```
<!-- This is a row -->
<div class="gamedes">
    <!-- this is a column -->
    <div class="miniaturas"><img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Google.png/800px-Google.png" /></div>
    <div class="gamede"><a href="game.php">Text for the link</a></div>
    <div class="description">This is a somewhat longer description here probably up to 120 characters</div>
</div>
```

In the css the key pieces are:

```
.gamedes { display: table-row; }
.miniaturas { display: table-cell; }
/* etc */
```

To see the whole thing running, take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hPLNK/4/

So, given this layout, all you have to do to add a new column now is add a new `<div>` inside of the "gamedes" and set the css display style to `table-cell`!

**Final Note** - The original code you provided had a few other issues that I fixed. A `<script>` tag is for including javascript. You seem to want to include text. An image tag can't have a `</img>` inside of it. Avoid using `<br/>` to force a height on a div or area. Instead use css based layouts.

**Small PHP Example**

In case you need some help getting the PHP back into this example, my recommendation is to put the php code inline. You end up with something like:

```
<div class="miniaturas"><img src="<? echo($imageUrl); ?>" /></div>
```

I made the assumption here that your image link is stored in "$imageUrl", but you get the idea. The nice thing about putting php inline like this is it reads a little more cleanly and editing the html becomes much easier. Best of luck!

Comment: Okey but I need this script because I need to take the description from a database

Comment: its a comment no an answer.

Comment: he asked how to add a column. where is the answer? i think my eyesight is failing me because i cant find it within your collection of comments.

Comment: @Banana I believe that may be better!

Comment: much better actually :) +1

Comment: Ok I thing I understand it but I need the php code and I don't know how I can put my php code here because it uses the same line of code
For example I have echo = 'Water'; and it repeats: water and in another line water and another water etc but I want two waters in the same line and down two more waters

Comment: @Ninjacu What you want is a loop and just echo the variables you need. I'll put a simple example of that in, but maybe you'll have to ask another stack question about this!

Comment: I need help I'm stressed because I don't know how I can do this Yes another question but I want to delete this and I can't because of the answers...

Comment: @Ninjacu On stack you will only get an answer to a specific code related issue. People aren't going to write code for you - which seems like what you might need. There are services you can pay to help you write code or you can hire a consultant if that is necessary as well. Hopefully my answer will at least point you in the right direction.